Missing items in my list of abbreviations
I was going sailing the other day, and made a list of important things I might need to know. But I was in a hurry, so I abbreviated them, and missed some out altogether.
What are the missing items? (And why?) You can give the full name of the missing items, you don't need to make an abbreviation.

King
North
South
Ties

Fort

Dog
Fish
Germ
Hum

Dove

Land
Mouth


Roy


Fast
Sea

Rock

Brides
Bail
Fair

Iceland


The OP appears to have been writing reminders...

 ...of the 31 UK shipping forecast areas (relevant to the sailing aspect of the flavour text). The abbreviations given are substrings of particular named sea regions (e.g. 'King' relates to 'VIKING' in the North Sea).

 The areas appear in the order that they are usually announced during BBC Radio 4's regular Shipping Forecast broadcast, which roughly follows the UK coast clockwise from the north-east.

The full list would be as follows:

 1. King = VIKING
 2. North = NORTH UTSIRE
 3. South = SOUTH UTSIRE
 4. Ties = FORTIES
 5. CROMARTY
 6. Fort = FORTH
 7. TYNE
 8. Dog = DOGGER
 9. Fish = FISHER
 10. Germ = GERMAN BIGHT
 11. Hum = HUMBER
 12. THAMES
 13. Dove = DOVER
 14. WIGHT
 15. Land = PORTLAND
 16. Mouth = PLYMOUTH
 17. BISCAY
 18. TRAFALGAR
 19. Roy = FITZROY
 20. SOLE
 21. LUNDY
 22. Fast = FASTNET
 23. Sea = IRISH SEA
 24. SHANNON
 25. Rock = ROCKALL
 26. MALIN
 27. Brides = HEBRIDES
 28. Bail = BAILEY
 29. Fair = FAIR ISLE
 30. FAEROES
 31. Iceland = SOUTHEAST ICELAND




I think you're overthinking this, or just don't listen to enough Radio 4 :-)  Link

@fljx Yes, that's 'overthinking' alright... I was trying to attribute much more of a rigid sequence here... Will amend, thanks.

Perfect answer. Good job.
